# changed front-page template gives 500 error

Tags: php, server

I need immediate help regarding WordPress website. i had to make some changes to the home page so i just download front-page template and what i did is made some changes just moved some blocks up and some of them down and reuploade the template now site is not loading itself . there is a 500 error on the server please need you help immediately what has happened

Server error

500

Comment: Do you have any backups?

Comment: *I need immediate help*. We all are here at our own pace and time, just like you. No one here are required to answer any question, neither are we forced to. Mind your manners and ask good questions and you question will be answered

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you might have done some syntax error etc please add these lines to wp-config.php to check error

If you have backup of your previous file, restore it to check error if any are there.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);
```

500 errors can frequently occur with incorrectly configured rewrite rules contained in your ".htaccess" files, so you should probably try removing those from your folders to see if it's the cause. Keep a backup of those files of course, you might still need them. But in your case it was working before and you had made changes in template file so reason seems like syntax error.

Thanks!